# Changing variables inside function called by eventListener doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a idle "game" and I ran into this problem. I wanted to make a calling of a function with an event listener which took a variable and added 1 (when ran) basicly:

```
const add = (x) =>{
    x = x + 1
}
foo.addEventListener("click", function(){add(var)})
```

I checked that the method to change a variable inside a function is through the return function; however this cant work here becouse I cant return to an eventlistener. Please Help

Comment: You cannot do that in JavaScript. You can arrange to do something *similar* in effect by passing an object and having the called function modify a property on the object.

Comment: `var` is a reserved keyword. Try using something else, like `apples`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with event listeners. It won't work if you call it anywhere else, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution by still using a value (a Number) as function's arg**

```js
// The function could return the result like so:
const add = (x) => {
  return x + 1;
}

var x = 5;
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");

// The caller should update "x" by the result of function:
foo.addEventListener("click", function () { 
  x = add(x); 
  console.log("x after click is: ", x);
});   
console.log("original x is: ", x);
```

```html
<button id="foo">click me (function with Number (value))</button>
```

**Solution by using an object/reference instead of a value as function's arg**

You can use an Object instead of a Number or String (or primitive types) value as function argument so that the modification in the function updates the object by reference (which is not possible by passing Number or String value).
See https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c

```js
const add = (xObject) => {
  if (!xObject || !xObject.count) {
    // Not a valid object
    return;
  }
  xObject.count++; // obj = obj + 1
}

let xObject = { count : 5 };
let foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("click", function () { 
  add(xObject); 
  console.log("number after click is: ", xObject);
});   
console.log("original number is: ", xObject);
```

```html
<button id="foo">click me (function with object (reference))</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Javascript` all primitive types (`numbers`, `strings`, etc...) are passed by value, except `objects` that are passed by the *`value of the reference`*. There is a good explanation [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-passing-by-value-vs-reference-explained-in-plain-english-8d00fd06a47c). So you can't do what I think you want to do, and I assume you want to pass the variable by `C-like reference`. However, one thing you can do (not recommended), is to use the global `window` object to access a global variable by his name.

```js
var x = 0;

const add = (x) => {
    window[x] = window[x] + 1;
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    add("x");
    console.log("x is now: " + x);
})
```

```html
<button id="test">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take another variable y and store plus 1 value. It is accessible after the click.

```js
var y=0;
 const add = (x) => {
        y = 1 + y;
    }
    var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
    foo.addEventListener("click", function () { add(); console.log(y) });
```

```html
<button id="foo">click me</button>
```

Comment: Both solutions does not work for me when running the snippets. (they always log 6, even after click, which seem indicate `y` ovject is not updated). 
See my answer to prevent use of another global variable, or use of out-dated callbacks (at least, in the form).

Comment: You are getting 6 because snippet is passing 5, and of course callbacks can never be outdated. They are improved in the form of promise, async.

Comment: They always log 6, even after click, which seem indicate `y` global object is not updated, which I think is what the OP is looking for. Callbacks are outdated at least in the form

Comment: As per question he want to pass var function(){add(var)}) and increase it by 1 so i wrote this. Defining y globally can solve the problem

Comment: Updated my answer.